# Http streaming on linux pc

Tags: linux, networking, apache-http-server, http, video-streaming

How to stream a video from one linux system to another through command line using http.
I have tried command: ffplay http://ipaddress:80/pathofvideofile.

But it returned an error. HTTP error 404 Not Found

Comment: With the information you have given, it is impossible to say more than: check the configurations of your router, network, firewalls and Apache.

Comment: Found answer . Create a folder at path /var/www/html and place all video files there on remote system(server).